# update call losing Date value in config variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-config

Hello I have an application that creates an object which holds a Date variable. The object is then passed into an http update function. Unfortunately, the update when it goes through everything looks great except the date is reset to 2018-06-06T04:00:00 instead of the actual time that was added. for testing purposes I ran the update query separately with the same object payload and it went through fine so I know is not the api. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

item in JSON used for payload:

{"id":10, "name":"test", "description":"test description", "startDate":"2018-06-06T23:30:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-06-07T02:30:00.000Z"}

Code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $resourceProvider, $httpProvider) {   
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"};

  //other code to set up routes, also added an interceptor to verify the data been sent, this is where I was able to see the data's Date time is reset.

});



//function to update

function updateObj(item){
    $http.put(urlToApi, item, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}})
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.log("ERROR: " + response);
     });
}
```

Comment: When you say that you have tested with same payload, do you mean the same payload and same way i.e. $http.put() ?

Comment: @PM. sorry for being vague, yes, I copied the json object from the console of my application and pasted it in Jmeter, with the same headers api url and put method and it worked with no problems

Comment: Can you paste your item object in your question?

Comment: @PM. sure thing I updated my question above with this info

Comment: That's weird, everything looks good. Should work!